# how to use <optgroup> in a foreach PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need that first displays the online users lable, and after that to display all the online users, and after that ends the first `<optgroup>`

the same for Offline and Idle too.

CODE:

```
foreach($alt_user_result as $cur_user) {
    if( $cur_user[user_status]=='online') {
        echo "<option class='green_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
        </option>";
    }
    elseif( $cur_user[user_status]=='idle') {
        echo "<option class='yellow_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
        </option>";
    }
    elseif( $cur_user[user_status]=='offline') {
        echo "<option class='gray_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
        </option>";
    }
}
```

i tried to add `<optgroup>` before `<option class='gray_status'` for example but then it will be like this

```
<optgroup><option></option><optgroup>
<optgroup><option></option><optgroup>
<optgroup><option></option><optgroup>
<optgroup><option></option><optgroup>
<optgroup><option></option><optgroup>
```

and i want like this:

```
    <optgroup lable="online">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <optgroup>


    <optgroup lable="offline">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <optgroup>

......
```

query:

```
$alt_user_result = execute_pdo_query("SELECT U.username, U.user_id, T.last_activity_time,
case WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) <= 5 THEN 'online'
 WHEN ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) > 5 AND
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) <=30 ) THEN 'idle'
    ELSE 'offline' end as user_status
     FROM user_skills S, users U
      LEFT JOIN user_status T ON U.user_id=T.user_id
         WHERE S.user_id=U.user_id and S.task_type_id=? and S.permission='Yes';",
           array($tablerow['task_type_id']));
```

Thanks all for the help in advance!

Comment: Is the `$alt_user_result` array currently sorted by online status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is sorted by online status, you can do something simple like this:

```
$prevGroup = '';

foreach($alt_user_result as $cur_user) {
    $curGroup = $cur_user['user_status'];

    if ($curGroup != $prevGroup) {
        if ($prevGroup != '') {
            echo '</optgroup>';
        }

        echo '<optgroup label="' . ucfirst($curGroup) . '">';
        $prevGroup = $curGroup;
    }

    if ($cur_user[user_status] == 'online') {
        echo "<option class='green_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
    </option>";
    } else if ($cur_user[user_status] == 'idle') {
        echo "<option class='yellow_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
    </option>";
    } else if ($cur_user[user_status] == 'offline') {
        echo "<option class='gray_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
    </option>";
    }
} // foreach

echo '</optgroup>';
```

If the array isn't sorted by online status, you can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to sort it prior to running the above code.

EDIT:  Here is `usort` code that will sort the array in the order you want [example](http://codepad.org/Re17oKuq):

```
function userStatusSort($a, $b) {
    $a = $a['user_status'];
    $b = $b['user_status'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($a == 'online') {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a == 'idle' && $b == 'offline') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man! see update please, i want `<optgroup>` for different status

Comment: The above code should put optgroups only around different statuses if the array is sorted by status which you said it was.  If it isn't then there will be optgroups all over the place.

Comment: yes i want to separate the result for `foreach` so will be like the example in the update above, how can i do that ? thanks!

Comment: Well I just made an edit to set the label of the optgroup tag, does that work any better?

Comment: yes, but for some reason the offline status is twice in the optgroup, don't know why... maybe i need to sort it as you said, how can i do that ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Would you do me a favor and provide me with a serialized copy of an array you are working with?  Do `echo base64_encode(serialize($alt_user_result));` and then give me that output.  That way I can work with the same data you are and hopefully get something working.

Comment: the echo breaks the page and doesn't display a thing :(, is it ok if i showed you the query ? or you need another thing ?

Comment: If you get a blank page that probably means there was a fatal error.  Having a copy of the array would be helpful so I can work with it.

Comment: from the looks of the query, the results are sorted in natural table order and not by status so the array would have to be sorted before using my code.

Comment: using order by ? or how can i do that ? appreciate it!

Comment: Casper's answer below may be better, just use PHP to group the different users.  You could add `ORDER BY user_status` in MySQL but the order would either be `idle, offline, online` or `online, offline, idle`.

Comment: You could also use `usort` in PHP to sort it the way you want.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to use usort, but didn't use it before, could you help me with that please ? i need it just simple online idle offline

Comment: :) you're welcome, glad to help and hopefully you can learn from that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start of by sorting the users into separate arrays

```
$online_users = array();
$offline_users = array();
$idle_users = array();

foreach($alt_user_result as $cur_user) {
    if($cur_user[user_status]=='online'){
        $online_users[] = $cur_user;
    }
 //and so forth...

}
```

and then echo out them

```
 echo "<optgroup>"
 foreach($online_users as $cur_user){
    echo "<option class='green_status' value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]
</option>";
echo "</optgroup>"

}
```